# Setting common Storybook.js for multiple project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

We have some React project, and we would like to setup a common Storybook and reuse component for this storybook.

We have thinking, to publish a npm package and import when we want on our react project.

But I can find a solution on internet, do you have some recommandations ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have one storybook for multiple react projects? If you are using git, how about submodules? You would have one storybook repo and importing it via submodules for all your front-end

Answer (score 0):

Actually we are working on a similar solution for now.

Here are some links that could help you

1. https://medium.com/@justintulk/how-to-turn-your-reusable-react-components-into-an-external-dependency-part-1-ae29b4d4e5
2. https://medium.com/@deividas.karzinauskas/sharing-react-components-across-our-react-apps-4e1245fe5433
3. https://blog.hichroma.com/how-packaging-makes-it-dead-simple-to-share-ui-components-29912593539d

The main solution looks like you have to pack each of your components into a private (or public - it's up to you) package. This is required for correct versioning. Otherwise, you can break the component implementation in other projects after you change smth in it.

After that adding packages to a single StoryBook project allows you to have a nice component library.